# How do I make a user profile field a link

Tags: entities, users

I've created a custom field for users on a site I'm working on that is for their website url. I want to make this field actually link to the website the users enter upon signing up.

Using Drupal 7, customized Bartik theme. The field is a standard text field.

I've tried doing a custom field template for that field, and I've tried editing the page-user.tpl.php file, neither worked.

Comment: are you wanting a link to their profile or to the website, eg, `drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4255/jimajamma` vs `drupal.stackexchange.com` or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly it sounds like you need an additional module that will correctly validate/display the link in the user profile.  Overview of the steps needed:

1. Download the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module:
2. Add a new field to the user profile of type "Link" (found in confifuration --> people --> account settings --> manage fields)[image]
3. Set any other config options you need